# Nextjs public folder with next-routes not working

Tags: reactjs, next.js

did anyone get the public folder working with custom express server and next-routes? getting 404 errors for all assets in public/asset

repo- https://github.com/msreekm/next9-custom-server-routes-example

Comment: you mean you want to create a public folder rather than statics and use the material inside ?

Comment: why don't you use statics folder ? is there a reason ?

Comment: @Afsanefda a strange question. `public` is clearly positioned as `static` replacement. There's even a console warning if you use `static`... The other thing is that `public` doesn't work correctly (at the moment)

Answer (score 3):

Nested `public` folders seem to be completely broken in latest NextJS. I'm personally switching back to `static`.

Comment: Can you share any specific issue thread ?

Answer (score 3):

There is a warning not to use static folder. If you will change from static to public you should change like this:

FROM
static/images/javascript-logo.png

```
<img src="/static/images/javascript-logo.png" alt="Javascript" height="200px" />
```

TO
public/images/javascript-logo.png

```
<img src="/images/javascript-logo.png" alt="Javascript" height="200px" />
```

OR

You should create public folder in root dir. Then you should move static folder to public folder. There will no need to change anything where it is used.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using custom `basePath: '/custom'` in your next.config.js,  the public folder must be like `custom/public`